# Linux Bash Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

What is wrong with my script? I don't see the problem, I'm sorry I'm new into Linux Shell Scripting.

```
# Skript: M122_Scripts/addPerson.sh
echo "Write youre name (: end with quit"
read $Name 
while true; do
if [ "$Name" = "quit" ]; then
echo "exit add person"
break
else
echo $name >> Filelist
echo $name
read $name
fi
done
```

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `$Name` != `$name`

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: `read $Name` should be `read Name` (no `$`)

Answer (score 2):

There are some mistakes in your script, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Write youre name (: end with quit"
# wrong: read $Name
read Name
while true; do
    if [ "$Name" = "quit" ]; then
        echo "exit add person"
        break
    else
        echo $Name >> Filelist
        echo $Name
        # wrong: read $name
        read Name
    fi
done
```

Comment: I've added the `# wrong:` comments for visibility of the changes

Comment: Also, I would recommend using `read -r` so backslashes will show in your variable.